# <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '19065171.'

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
for i in range(0, len(terceros_df.NIT)):
    print 'esto es i =', i
    number = terceros_df.iloc[i]['NIT']
    length = len(str(number))
    if length == 10:
        str_number = str(number)
        nit = str_number[:-1]
        dv = str_number[-1:]
        nit = format(int(nit), ',d').replace(',', ".")+ "-" + str(dv)
        terceros_df.loc[i,'NIT'] = nit
        print nit
    else:
        number = format(int(number), ',d').replace(',', ".")
        terceros_df.loc[i,'NIT'] = number
        print number
    print 'La cantidad de caracteres son:',length
    print '-----------------------'
```

El error es:

```
 <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '19065171.
```

Segun entiendo, se esta intentado leer un float, pero le estoy pasando un entero, en resumen como resultado deseamos un entero no un float. como solucionar?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el proposito de las manipulaciones que haces con `number`, `str_number` y `nit`? ¿Qué formato tienen los datos de la columna `NIT` y a qué los quieres convertir?

Answer (score 1):

No estás pasando un entero. Estás pasando un float. El valor que te da error es `'19065171.'`. El problema está en que acaba con un punto.

```
>>> int('19065171.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '19065171.'
```

Así que si vas a tratar como cadena la cifra, **siempre que se traten de cifras con un solo decimal**, lo lógico sería que establecer nit desde el penúltimo caracter:

```
>>> number = 19065171.4
>>> str_number = str(number)
>>> nit = str_number[:-2]
>>> int(nit)
19065171
```

Comment: el valor original es de tipo entero, al cargar el dataframe se convierte a float, intentando mantener el valor como entero aplico `terceros_df['NIT'] = terceros_df['NIT'].fillna(-1).astype(int)` **pero se presenta el siguiente error:** `<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '19.065.171'`

Comment: El problema siguen siendo los puntos. Yo probaría a quitarlos antes de la conversión `.astype(int)` con `str.replace(',', '')`